# Execute shell commands by ProcessBuilder In java but seems nothing work

Tags: java, kubectl, processbuilder

I want to export the selected database in a container. When using shells commands I use this

```sh
kubectl exec -it pg-container -n data-prod -- /bin/bash -c "pg_dump -U nsc -d nsc -n public -f nsc.sql"
```

when data-prod is namespace and pg-container is the container having PostgreSQL database.

This command works well in the shell. But I want to execute this command in Java using ProcessBuilder.

The implementation in java is like this:

```
public class ExportDBInfo {
        String dbname;
        String schemaname;
        ArrayList<String> tablesname;
        String dbuser;
        String output;
    }
for (ExportDBInfo dbinfo : Array_db_info){
            String export_database_cmd = String.format("kubectl exec -it pg-container -n data-prod -- /bin/bash -c \"pg_dump -U %s -d %s -n %s %s -f %s.sql\"",dbinfo.dbuser,dbinfo.dbname,dbinfo.schemaname,query_tables,dbinfo.output);
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(export_database_cmd);
            pb.start().waitFor();
}
```

But that doesn't work. I'm wondering if there are some mistakes in my implementation.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java isn't bash, or shell. You don't really ever want to use `exec`, its rules are somewhat bizarre. It tries very haphazardly to split on spaces.

Instead, use `ProcessBuilder`, and specify a *list* of arguments, not the single string variant.

That whole pg_dump thing is a **single argument** and should **not** contain quotes - those quotes are 'eaten' by bash and tell bash to treat it all as a single argument; java isn't bash and just blindly passes them to the kubectl tool which doesn't know what it means.

All the other args (including `--`) are their own thing.

So..

```
List.of("/bin/kubectl", "exec", "-it", "pg-container", "-n", "data-prod", "--", "/bin/bash", "-c", String.format("pg_dump -U %s -d %s -n %s %s -f %s.sql", dbinfo.dbuser, dbinfo.dbname, dbinfo.schemaname, query_tables, dbinfo.output));
```

And pass that to the constructor of `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: NICE！ This answer works! I'm new to ProcessBuilder, Thank you a lot! Have a nice day!